# C# Image.Save() cause Cannot access a closed Stream when saving JPG file (PNG works)

Tags: c#, image, jpeg

I've got strange behavior.

I have a code, when I am sending byte[] array to the Image (sometimes png, sometimes jpg).

When I save PNG format - everything is ok, but when I am trying to save JPG, there is an exception: "Cannot access a closed Stream"

Code:

```
imgTarget.Save(wwwroot + "\\ImageBank\\" + TaskRunID + "_" + TestCaseID + "_" + TestDataID + "_" + ImageCounter + Extension, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

What I have checked:

- imgTarget is not null
- imgTarget contains correct data (even RawFormat is Png or Jpeg as It should)
- imgTarget.Save() throws an exception: System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a closed Stream.'
- I have tried to use Bitmap - copy imgTarget to new Bitmap and then Save (with the same result)
- I have tried to call Save() method with the ImageFormat parameter correctly set to jpeg or png (with the same result) - for both for Image.Save() and Bitmap.Save()
- I have checked the correct path and file name (it's ok) (in this case it is C:\MyProd\wwwroot\ImageBank\10611_8_-1_1.jpeg)

Strange is that imgTarget contains data just before calling the method Save() - but right after it is null/disposed...

Anyone any ideas?

**EDIT:**

I have prepared little bit of code which is failing in the same way - it fails at last line .Save()

```
// This contains only the URL for the downloading of the file
string url = $"***url to download jpg file***";

// Request for the API - which downloads the jpg file via GET and provide the RawData via Response.RawBytes
APIRequest request = new APIRequest(RestSharp.Method.GET, url, new Authentication("user", "password", "-1"));

// Test case is only class which calls RestSharp (get png or jpg file)
TestCase t = new TestCase();
// This downloads the jpg file and store it as byte[] in t.GetDataFromAPI
t.API(request);
// Using downloaded data as byte[]
byte[] APIImageSource = t.GetDataFromAPI;
// Default extensions for saving files is .png
string Extension = ".png";
            

Image imgTarget;
// Now I use bytes[] and convert them into the image
imgTarget = ConvertBytesToImage(APIImageSource);
if (t.GetImageFormat(APIImageSource) == ExpectedFormat.JPEG)
{
     Extension = ".jpeg";
}
string path = "C:\\Temp\\filename" + Extension;
imgTarget.Save(path + Extension, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

There is Method ConvertBytesToImage:

```
internal static Image ConvertBytesToImage(byte[] bytes)
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        return Image.FromStream(ms);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check that everything is disposed when it should, and no earlier. A possible reason is that png and jpg might take different times to save, so give different opportunities for GC/finallization to be run.

Comment: Could you [create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Please show the relevant parts of your code (opening/closing streams, dispose calls and/or using-blocks, etc.).

Comment: You are going to have to give us more code than that

Comment: @nilsK, Charlieface - question updated with the code

Comment: You don't seem to use a Stream with your image. What is the full stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @JosefŠirůčka - You can only `@` notify one person per message. The notifications don't go thru to the second person.

Comment: @JosefŠirůčka - Please read the [mcve] page thoroughly. A key part is the "verifiable" part. We need to be able to verify that your code acts they way you say it does. That means you need to give us the instructions to run your code.

Comment: Comments into the code added and added also method used for converting the bytes to Image

Comment: remove the using on the MemoryStream, or remove that ConvertBytesToImage and keep the MemoryStream alive until you completely saved the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment from @Simon Mourier is the solution:

remove the using on the MemoryStream, or remove that ConvertBytesToImage and keep the MemoryStream alive until you completely saved the image. – Simon Mourier 1 min ago

I don't understand why, but I have removed the using statement and now it works.

Thank all of You

Comment: It's because GDI+ uses a stream passed to Image.FromStream as On-Demand: it only gets from it when needed, which can happen here too late (stream has been closed).

Comment: Removing the `using` statement is a bad idea. It makes the code work for small units of work, but it will cause an out of memory error for large or lengthy units of work. You need to solve this a different way. The memory stream, images, etc, any thing `IDisposable`, needs to be manually disposed of. Needs to be.

Comment: @Enigmativity  should I dispose the imgTarget right after the Save() right?

Comment: @JosefŠirůčka - You should always dispose it as soon as practicable after its use. You should dispose of all of your disposables - including the `MemoryStream`.